# What does mean ` AWK=@AWK@` in shell scripting

Tags: shell-script, bash-script, variable

I found  `AWK=@AWK@` while reading `sh` script, it's something like `AWK=$(which awk)`, but it's not working.
So can anyone explain this ?

Script :

```
#!/bin/sh -
# makelist.sh: Automatically generate header files...

AWK=@AWK@
USAGE="Usage: $0 -n|-h|-e|-fc|-fh|-bc|-bh|-m <filenames>"

if [ "x$1" = "x" ]
then
    echo $USAGE 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

.....
.....
.....
-h)
    set - `echo $FILES | sed -e 's/\\./_/g'`
    hdr="_h_`basename $1`"
    cat $FILES | $AWK '
        BEGIN {
            printf("/* Automatically generated file, do not edit */\n");
            printf("#ifndef %s\n#define %s\n", "'$hdr'", "'$hdr'");
        }
        /\(\):/ {
            pr = substr($2, 1, 2);
            if (pr == "vi" || pr == "em" || pr == "ed") {
                # XXXMYSQL: support CRLF
                name = substr($2, 1, index($2,"(") - 1);
...
```

Comment: Can you maybe show a larger part of the script?

Comment: Updated the some script content which related to question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says `# makelist.sh: Automatically generate header files...`.

It probably means some other program is going to edit the shell script and replace the placemarker `@AWK@` with the real path to awk, like `/usr/bin/awk`.

Comment: but why they should do this complex way ?

Comment: I don't really see a good reason for that, but some people do it. The right and portable way to find the path for a command is in my opinion `command -v awk`.

Comment: `command -v awk` seem too faster than `which awk`

Comment: your ans seems to me approximately correct not 100%, waiting for other answers.  Are you work in creating this stuff like configure makefile in source code package, that why you are saying Or you just jugging this ?

Comment: I have done some Debian packaging already, and I saw `@word@` as a placemark a few times and used it myself once to refer to a list of files that was going to be created during the make process.